# Error: "You are passing an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers"

Tags: api, keras, gradient, loss-function

I am using tensorflow.keras and trying to compute the divergence of the network output.

This is my code:

```
x = Input(shape=(3,), name='strains')
x_t = Reshape((1, 3))(strains)
for i in range(n_layers):
    hidden = Dense(units=n_neurons, activation=act_fun)(strains_t)
f = Dense(units=3, activation='relu', name='out')(hidden)
model = Model(inputs=strains, outputs=f)

def custom_loss(i):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # Divergence error
        f = y_pred.numpy()
        
        tri = Triangulation(X, Y)
        Fx = LinearTriInterpolator(tri, f[:, 0, 0] + f[:, 0, 2])
        Fy = LinearTriInterpolator(tri, f[:, 0, 1] + f[:, 0, 2])
        gradx = Fx.gradient(X, Y)
        grady = Fy.gradient(X, Y)
        div = gradx[0] + grady[0] + gradx[1] + grady[1]
        L_div = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(tf.constant(div.flatten())))

        # Integral error
        Wi = tf.reduce_sum((tf.linalg.matmul(tf.expand_dims(i, 1), tf.transpose(y_pred, perm=[0, 2, 1]))), axis=0)
        Wext = tf.reduce_mean(y_true, axis=0)
        L_en = tf.abs(Wi - Wext)

        # Total weighted error
        loss = 0.095*tf.constant(L_div) + 0.05*tf.cast(L_en, dtype=tf.float64)
        return loss
    return loss

model.compile(loss=custom_loss(x), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[], run_eagerly=True)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          batch_size=2500,
          epochs=100,
          shuffle=False, callbacks=[early_stop],
          verbose=1)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_421'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

I ve been looking all around the web for a solution, but someone reccomedn to disable the eagerly optin, but doing this I can not convert the y_pred into numpy anymore for the computation of the grdient on an arbitrari grid.